# Merging buffers together with no fill colour?

Tags: buffer, merge

I am a bit of a novice with GIS.

I have created several 500m buffer zones around streets in GIS. I ultimately want a combined buffer so only the outside line that measures 500m away from all of these streets can be seen on the map.

I have tried Merge-ing and then Dissolve-ing the buffers I have created around each street but whenever I remove the colour fill the map appears to resort back to the original with all the lines of all buffer zones apparent.

Could somebody advise me on how to combine my buffers and remove the overlapping outlines in the centre?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you please *edit* your question and include information about the software (including version) you are using.

Comment: In Arc, either merge or Dissolve should be doing what you want. However Dissolve will produce a new layer/dataset, so it's possible you're seeing the original, undissolved layer when you change the fill of the dissolved one.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using ArcGIS 10.x or Pro**

When you are creating your buffer there should be a "dissolve type" option. For this you will select ALL. This should dissolve the buffers as they are created to make one large overall buffer. Then with the symbology you can make it so it is just represented by an outline by making the fill color set to no color.

EDIT: This will require that your streets are all in one layer.